# Как вернуть два значений из функции в C#

Tags: c#

у меня есть такой код, и я хочу вернуть x и y, как это сделать? как вы поняли return x, y;
не работает

```
       {
           x = x + y;
           y = x - y;
           x = x - y;
           return x, y;
       }
```

Comment: например можно в виде объекта........ или кортежа

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.tuple?view=net-6.0

Comment: static (T x, T y) Swap<T>(T x, T y) => (y, x);

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin: Если есть туплы, функция не нужна. Просто пишете `(x, y) = (y, x);` и всё.